# solving:$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 4x}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the values of $x$ such that $$\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 4x}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I think this is very straight forward. What did you try ?

Comment: Square roots are a pain in the neck, aren't they? Do you know a good way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqaure both sides:
$$\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Multiply by two 
$$1+\cos(4x)=1$$
subtract one from both sides:
$$\cos(4x)=0$$
$\cos(y)=0$ when $y=\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So we have to satisfy $4x=\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. So your solution for $x$ should be $x=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{n\pi}{4}$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $cos(x)=cos(y)=>x=(+ou−)y+2npi$ you forgot $2$ .And how about the second case ,the minus (-)?

Comment: Since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ it can be both negative or non-negative. Furthermore the question is not concerned with $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$, I merely temporarily introduced the $y$ to make it a little clearer that for this question $y=4x=\frac{\pi}{2}+ n\pi$.

Comment: yes but it's not correct in other situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2} =\cos^2 x$$

Comment: That'll work, but, surprisingly, may be the hard way.